# how to get property value using PropertyInfo in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to iterate over all properties marked with HtmlAttributeNameAttribute and return the property value, but I can't figure out how to get the actual value.

**Code**:

```
public void ProcessAttributes<TTagHelper>(TTagHelper tagHelper) where TTagHelper : TagHelperBaseBETA
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TTagHelper).GetProperties();

    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);

        foreach(object attr in attrs)
        {
            HtmlAttributeNameAttribute att = attr as HtmlAttributeNameAttribute;

            if (att != null)
            {
                string name = att.Name;
                string value = ??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `prop.getValue(tagHelper)`

Comment: Note that you could also just do `HtmlAttributeNameAttribute[] attrs = (HtmlAttributeNameAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HtmlAttributeNameAttribute), true)`